# How to create custom nUnit 3 category attribute

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, nunit-3.0

How can I create a custom category attribute for nUnit 3?

I have created one like so:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class UnitTestAttribute : CategoryAttribute
{
}
```

According to https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Category-Attribute, that would make a category called "UnitTest".

And I'm using it like so:

```
[Test]
[UnitTest]
public void ExampleTest()
{
    // Example test goes here
}
```

As far as I know this should work but in Resharper 2017.2's Unit Test Explorer, Group by Categories, I only have "Uncategorized" tests.

If I change:

```
[UnitTest]
```

to

```
[Category("Unit Test")]
```

Then it works.

Any ideas?

I'm using Visual Studio Professional 2017 Version 15.4.3

Comment: This is likely a bug to do with how ReSharper looks for categories. Try running with the NUnit 3 test adapter in Visual Studio, I imagine that recognises the categories correctly?

Comment: I already have the nUnit3 Test Adapter.
Someone just answered the question but it's gone? I'll answer the question with his/her response as it fixed my problem.

Comment: It was me, but the answer was wrong! I'll comment on your answer as to why. =)

Comment: Oh good, thought I was losing my mind for a second there, the wiki changes were also undone.

Comment: What changes? 0:-)

Comment: Actually - I just tried this, and it works fine for me! Try updating ReSharper to the latest version?

Comment: Full comment: What you have above 'should' work. ReSharper sometimes takes shortcuts to speed up test discovery, which can miss out cases like this - which is what I thought may be happening here. Actually, maybe you need to run the tests to have ReSharper discover this category? Note of course the category will actually be `UnitTest`, not `Unit Test`.

Comment: I have checked my Resharper and it is up to date and I've tried running them to try and discover all the categories and that didn't help. The previous answer you gave works, why was it wrong? "UnitTest" will do just fine.

Comment: It's not 'wrong' as such - it just shouldn't be necessary. What you have originally should work just fine. You're right, about ReSharper sorry, I have the 2017.3 EAP. There's a chance they may just have fixed it in that...

Comment: I tried EAP but that didn't help, using the constructor didn't help either, it works sometimes with the custom attribute (with and without the constructor), but it always works without the custom attribute.

Answer (score 0):

It should work as I've done in my question, you can create a constructor that calls the base class to specify the name, but it's not required. It doesn't always seem to work with the custom attribute. It does always seem to work by just using the CategoryAttribute directly.

This is an example of creating the custom attribute with the constructor.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class UnitTestAttribute : CategoryAttribute
{
    public UnitTestAttribute():base ("Unit Test")
    {

    }
}
```